# How can i have all the li tags under the ul tag?

Tags: jquery

I am getting this as response from the server

```
{
    "vendors": {
        "T1": [
            {
                "name": "Raj Cool Drinks",
                "leaf": [
                    {
                      "toppings": [
                         {
                           "name": "Quantity      1",
                           "value": [
                               "Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML",
                               "Honey with Carmel  10 ML"
                               ]
                         }
                      ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

for (var l = 0; l < toppins.length; l++) {
    var toppul = '<ul>';
    $.each(toppins[l].value, function (i, text) {
        if (text != '' && text != undefined) {
            toppul += "<li>" + text + "</li>";
        }
        toppul += "</ul>";
    });
}
```

With the above code , the output is being formed this way

```
<div class="crust-topping-detailsWrap">
    <h5>Item 1</h5>
    <h6>Toppings</h6>
    <ul>
         <li>Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Honey with Carmel  10 ML</li>
```

And the screen looks this way

[image]

How can i have all the text under the ul ??

So that the output look this way

```
  <ul>
      <li>Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML</li>
      <li>Honey with Carmel  10 ML</li>

  </ul>
```

Comment: you have `toppul += "</ul>";` within the `each()` loop, move it outside..

Comment: always use code indentation to avoid this kind if problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move this following statement outside .each loop

```
toppul += "</ul>";
```

---

```
$.each(toppins[l].value, function(i, text) {
   if(text!=''&&text!=undefined)
   { 
      toppul += "<li>" + text + "</li>";
   }     
});

toppul += "</ul>"; // Out side .each loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the location of `"</ul>"`

```
for(var l=0;l<toppins.length;l++)
    {
    var toppul = '<ul>';
    $.each(toppins[l].value, function(i, text) {
    if(text!=''&&text!=undefined)
    { 
        toppul += "<li>" + text + "</li>";
    }
    });
     toppul += "</ul>";
    }
```

You have included the close of `<ul>` tag within the `<li>` loop

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var l=0;l<toppins.length;l++)
{
var toppul = '<ul>';
$.each(toppins[l].value, function(i, text) {
if(text!=''&&text!=undefined)
{ 
    toppul += "<li>" + text + "</li>";
}
 toppul += "</ul>";
});
}
```

change to

```
for(var l=0;l<toppins.length;l++)
{
var toppul = '<ul>';
$.each(toppins[l].value, function(i, text) {
if(text!=''&&text!=undefined)
{ 
    toppul += "<li>" + text + "</li>";
}
});
 toppul += "</ul>";
}
```

or even

```
var toppul = '<ul>';
for(var l=0;l<toppins.length;l++)
    {
    $.each(toppins[l].value, function(i, text) {
    if(text!=''&&text!=undefined)
    { 
        toppul += "<li>" + text + "</li>";
    }
    });
    }
toppul += "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    for(var l=0;l<toppins.length;l++)
    {
        var toppul = '<ul>';
        $.each(toppins[l].value, function(i, text) {
            if(text!=''&&text!=undefined)
            { 
                toppul += "<li>" + text + "</li>";
            }
        });
        toppul += "</ul>";// Shifted this line.
    }
```

Append the `</ul>` after the inner for loop.